# How to calculate peak concurrent users given session log

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a session start time, session end time, and duration (in hours). I'm trying to figure out a way to find amount of concurrent users by hour.

I used a brute force method that would check each hour bucket against all the rows to see if it fit the condition (if the start time is within the bucket, if the end time is within the bucket, or does the session start and end outside of the bucket)

I also used a self join method that I found on a lot of other similar discussion threads on stackoverflow but the results differed a bit with the my brute force method.

Basically I'm trying to find if theres a way to accurately find concurrent users without having to brute force (loop over x records for y amount of hours).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you refer as brute force but it's not terrible

```
with sample as (
select timestamp('2020-01-01 05:50:00') as session_start_time,timestamp('2020-01-01 05:59:00') session_end_time union all
select timestamp('2020-01-01 04:51:00') as session_start_time,timestamp('2020-01-01 05:58:00') session_end_time union all
select timestamp('2020-01-01 03:52:00') as session_start_time,timestamp('2020-01-01 05:57:00') session_end_time union all
select timestamp('2020-01-01 02:53:00') as session_start_time,timestamp('2020-01-01 05:56:00') session_end_time union all
select timestamp('2020-01-01 01:54:00') as session_start_time,timestamp('2020-01-01 05:55:00') session_end_time union all
select timestamp('2020-01-01 05:55:00') as session_start_time,timestamp('2020-01-01 05:56:00') session_end_time 

), base as (
select 
session_start_time, session_end_time, row_number() over( order by session_start_time) ses_id
from sample

),
buckets as (
select timestamp_trunc(ts, hour) bucket  from 
unnest(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY((select TIMESTAMP_SUB(min(session_start_time), interval  1 hour)  from sample), 
(select TIMESTAMP_ADD(max(session_end_time), interval  1 hour)  from sample), INTERVAL 1 hour )) ts
 
)

select bucket, count(distinct if(buckets.bucket between base.session_start_time and base.session_end_time, ses_id,null))
from buckets 
cross join base  
group by 1
```